# How can I test signed or permanent cookies with rspec?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can write cookies to the request fine with:

```
request.cookies['foo'] = 'bar'
```

But none of these work:

```
request.cookies.permanent['foo'] = 'bar'
request.cookies.signed['foo'] = 'bar'
request.cookies.permanent.signed['foo'] = 'bar' # what I really want
```

I get empty hash messages like messages like this:

```
NoMethodError:
    undefined method `signed' for {}:Hash
```

How can I create these cookies for my tests?

I am using rails 3.1 and rspec 2.6.0.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
cookies.permanent['foo'] = 'bar'
cookies.signed['foo'] = 'bar'
cookies.permanent.signed['foo'] = 'bar'
```

Instead

Comment: This raises an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'signed' for #<Rack::Test::CookieJar:0x00007fda08f10c68>`

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following Rails helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def set_cookie(name, value)
    cookies.permanent.signed[name] = value
  end
end
```

To test this in **Rails 3.2.6** using **RSpec 2.11.0**, you could do the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do
  it "should set a permanent, signed cookie" do
    cookies.should_receive(:permanent).once.and_return(cookies)
    cookies.should_receive(:signed).once.with(:user_id, 12345)
    helper.set_cookie(:user_id, 12345)
  end
end
```

I've never run into problems using rspec to test `cookies.signed[:foo].should == 'bar'`, but throwing in a call to `cookies.permanent` has given me problems in the past. Above, I'm really just stubbing the `permanent` method and returning the `cookies` object again. This allows me to test that it has been called.

You really shouldn't have to worry about weather rails *itself* set a permanent cookie because that has been tested already.

Comment: Failure/Error: response.cookies.should_receive(:permanent).once.and_return(cookies)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `should_receive' for #<Hash:0x007ffe4dcf34d0>

Comment: gotta enable mocking